# Pythonic/djangonic way to handle user timeouts on the scale of seconds (or minutes if need be)

Tags: python, ajax, django, session, django-middleware

The closest example to my case is a Django ajax chat application. The rooms need to keep a list of active users. Aside from displaying that list of users within the chat, a given room might have a maximum number of active users; new users need to be blocked from entering if there's no room.

Currently I have the chat client page calling a poll view every second via ajax. The poll view returns the text of the room. I figure poll can just also do some type of pinging -- adding users to an active_user M2M field on the Room object (I have all of this in place so far). What I need next is something that drops users from that active_user list after some kind of timeout.

I imagine there's two ways to do this, and I'm wondering which would be more efficient for an app that needs to be accurate to the second (or ten/fifteen seconds):

- Using cookies / sessions / middleware a la [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644471/how-do-i-determine-when-a-user-has-an-idle-timeout-in-django) (however it seems to me that this method wouldn't work for moment-to-moment info
- Another model, such as an explicit Users_Rooms 'through' table with a datetime field for the time that is updated upon creation and with every ping following, and write some function that cleans up the old ones

That's all I can think of. I'm just trying to figure out whether hitting mySQL every second for every user for every room is a good idea, and wondering if that second is indeed the *best* option for the task. Thanks!

Comment: Since chat sessions probably don't need to survive server reboots, and  the number of participants is in low thousands per machine at best, you can store users' ping timestamps in a small in-memory key-value store. It could be a separate DB if you restart your Django processes often, or just be the cache as @Ivan-Kharlamov suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use sessions and store last ping `datetime` as a session parameter. Don't worry about database hits, if at the certain point you would feel that you're getting too many of them, just switch your session storage to [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions).

Make your application robust to cache-flushing.

One of my friends used to host a relatively popular django-based social networking game on a pretty much standard virtual private server, and it took a while before he was forced to switch to cache-based sessions.